# После удаления удалено репозитория , не могу сделать push

Tags: git

Ребят , проблема c git . Я не правильно запушала файлы , команду написала git remote origin master и получилось 2 ветки .( мне нужно было main )  Я удалённо удалила репозиторий удалённо через настройки . В терминале хотела снова запушить но на main , но выдаёт ошибку nothing to commit. В терминале я прописала что главная ветка main . Но все равно не даёт запушить . Подскажите пожалуйста что делать ?(

Comment: Сделайте любое изменение в локальном репозитории. Например создайте пустой текстовый файл и запуште

Comment: Я все удалила и локально и удалено . Заново создала проект локально , и создала репозиторий удалено . Прошла все состояния файла git . И на последнем когда надо git push делать он выдаёт ошибку .  Я снова в ветке master .

Comment: В терминале прописала команду git branch —move master main . Теперь я в main . Удалённо на репозитории стоит только одна ветка main . Но все равно ошибки при push .

Comment: Товарищи )), я написала команду git push -u -f origin main и все перенеслось . Но теперь мне всегда такую команду что ли писать ?((.

Comment: Сделайте ещё один коммит и посмотрите :)